# How to compile Jigsaw http server on Linux?

Tags: linux, compilation, classpath

I download the Jigsaw server source from w3c website, http://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/. I followed its instruction http://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/Doc/Programmer/compile.html, but still can not compile it on my linux. What does it mean to update your CLASSPATH to compile Jigsaw and use the new compiled classes? How could I set my classpath?

Plz give me some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you need to set the `$CLASSPATH` environment variable.  I haven't looked at Jigsaw, but if you wanted to set your `$CLASSPATH` to include all the jar files within a directory (for example one that contains all the Jigsaw compiled jars) then you can use this script fragment:

```
CLASSPATH=""
for j in $(find /path/to/jigsaw/lib -name \*.jar)
do
    if [ ! -z "$CLASSPATH" ]; then CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:"; fi
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH$j"
done
```

Now whenever you invoke the `java` command it will use the classes within `/path/to/jigsaw/lib`.

However this is not a good idea; better is to use the above technique to build an environment variable other than `$CLASSPATH` and pass that as the argument to the `java -cp`  command line option:

```
cp=""
for j in $(find /path/to/jigsaw/lib -name \*.jar)
do
    if [ ! -z "$cp" ]; then cp="$cp:"; fi
    cp="$cp$j"
done
java -cp $cp ...
```